# Ember components without wrapping in .ember-view class?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create a component for a carousel but if I iterate through the HTML with Ember components it wraps each slide with  which breaks the structure of the html.

It should be:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li>This is a slide.</li>
        <li>This is another slide.</li>
        <li>This is a final slide.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But it turns into:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <div class="ember-view">
            <li>This is a slide.</li>
        </div>
        <div class="ember-view"> 
            <li>This is another slide.</li>
        </div>
        <div class='ember-view'>
            <li>This is a final slide.</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do you solve this?

Are components the wrong thing to use for this?

Comment: Can you show the code of your component?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modify the [tagName](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_tagName) of the component:

```
App.CarouselSlideComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li'
});
```

Usage:

```
<ul>
  {{#each slides}}
    {{#carousel-slide}}
      {{content}}
    {{/carousel-slide}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

---

Or pass it inline:

```
<ul>
  {{#each slides}}
    {{#carousel-slide tagName="li"}}
      {{content}}
    {{/carousel-slide}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template use the unbound Handlebars helper like so: `{{{value}}}`. You will lose the value binding though.